# Get the "id" of the TD Node

Tags: html-table

I'm trying to get the "id" of the TD Node that a field is in.  I created a function, but I am not getting the data out of the loop ... I'm guessing that the variables are out of scope and I can't figure out how to make it work.

```
function getTD(vStartNm)
{
vNm = document.getElementsByName(vStartNm),
vId = vNm[0].getAttribute('id'),
vNode = document.getElementById(vId),
vTag = vNode.nodeName;
vTDId = '';
for (i = 0; i >10; i++) 
 {
  vPar = vNode.parentNode;
  vTag = vPar.nodeName;
  vTDId = vPar.id;
  vNode = vPar;
  if (vTag == 'TD'){return vTDId; break;}
}
}

vTD_id = getTD('udfchar45');
vTD = document.getElementById(vTD_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

my syntax on the do loop may be wrong.  once i changed it to a while loop, it seems to work just fine.

```
function getTD(vStartNm)
{
vNm = document.getElementsByName(vStartNm),
vId = vNm[0].getAttribute('id'),
vNode = document.getElementById(vId),
vTag = vNode.nodeName;
vTDId = '';
i=0;
while (i < 10)
 {
  i++;
  vPar = vNode.parentNode;
  vTag = vPar.nodeName;
  vTDId = vPar.id;
  vNode = vPar;
  if (vTag == 'TD'){return vTDId; break;}
}
}
vTD_id = getTD('udfchar45');
vTD = document.getElementById(vTD_id);
```